# How to pull Call/Put Option prices with pandas-datareader in Python?

Tags: python, trading, quantitative-finance, pandas-datareader

I have the following code. I tried to pull the data from yahoo and google, both don't work. It's throwing the below message

```
from pandas_datareader.data import Options

fb_options = Options('TSLA', 'yahoo')
options_df = fb_options.get_options_data(expiry=fb_options.expiry_dates[0])

print(options_df.tail())
```

> Error Message: Yahoo Options has been immediately deprecated due to large breaks in the API without the
> introduction of a stable replacement. Pull Requests to re-enable these data
> connectors are welcome.

Is there any other way to retrieve the options prices?

Answer (score 5):

The following is working for me right now

```
import yfinance as yf # https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance
aapl= yf.Ticker("AAPL")
# aapl.options # list of dates 
DF_calls, DF_puts = aapl.option_chain(aapl.options[0]) # returns 2 DataFrames
```

Alternative method

```
import  pandas_datareader as pdr
aapl = Options('aapl')
calls = aapl.get_call_data()
```

Partial output:

```
Last    Bid Ask Chg Vol Open_Int    IV  Underlying_Price    Last_Trade_Date                                 
200.0   2020-07-02  call    AAPL200702C00200000 164.50  151.60  156.20  0.000000    13.0    13.0    1.962891    353.63  2020-06-23 13:30:03
```

[Link to my project code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NSCsxBvhIZuZu6aHcP3qLPEciBokmuWO?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo ended support for their options API, and as such, the Yahoo options reader and `get_options_data` were [deprecated](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/450) in `pandas_datareader` 0.7.0 (marked for removal). Unfortunately, there are no other readers in `pandas_datareader` which provide options prices.

There are (to my knowledge) no free-to-use APIs for options data, other than TD Ameritrade (see [this](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/option-chains/apis) endpoint), though you must be a TD Ameritrade account holder to obtain access to their developer API ([link](https://developer.tdameritrade.com)).